# React styling bootstrap Modal

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I want to add style my modal so it has (making the modal the full width of the screen and pushing it down the screen):

```
width: "100%,
top: "25px
```

to the

```
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
```

as it appears on the regular bootstrap modal (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), or when react-bootstrap is used, the div is

```
<div class="custom-modal modal-lg modal-dialog">
```

but looking at the react-bootstrap site, (https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#modals) we only have access too

```
<Modal/>
<Modal.Header/>
<Modal.Body/>
```

and applying those CSS settings to those won't give me the styling im looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look to the Props section for modals, it explains what possible customisations can be set on each of those (Modal, Modal.Header, Modal.Body).

For example, to add a `custom-modal` class to the `modal-dialog` element, the property `dialogClassName` can be set:

```
<Modal dialogClassName="custom-modal">
    //Modal content goes here
</Modal>
```

[Property documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#modals-props)

[Example with custom css class](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#modal-custom-sizing)